# Recursive Time Complexity With Fibonacci Numbers?

Tags: time, time-complexity

```java
public static int recurC(int n) {
   if(n==1)
      return 1;
   return n + recurC(n-1) + recurC(n-2);
}
```

So I need to find the formal equation for T(n). I set it up as a recurrence relation with T(n) = C + T(n-1) + T(n-2). However, when I tried to evaluate it out, I got nowhere. The relation with each subsequent recursive call isn't entirely clear to me. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the recurrence relation below:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + C
T(0) = T(1) = 1
Notice that T(n-1) ≈ T(n-2), that is to say:
Number of operations performed with input size n - 1 is approximately equal to the number of operations performed with input size n - 2. 
Therefore, we can show that:
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + C
T(n) ≈ 2T(n-2) + C
T(n) ≈ 4T(n-4) + 3C
T(n) ≈ 8T(n-6) + 7C
       ...
T(n) = 2^k*T(n-2k) + (2^k-1)*C
n-2k = 0  --> k = n/2
T(n) = 2^(n/2) + (2^(n/2)-1)*C
T(n) = (1 + C)*2^(N/2) - C
```

Therefore we can conclude that, `T(n)` ∈ `O(2^(n/2))`